# Hugo webserver not reaching my Windows vm

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, hugo

I want to test my website on edge and internet explorer so I tried using a windows VM, I am currently on linux mint 19.1, I start the gohugo server with "hugo server --disableFastRender" and create the VM in virtualbox using bridged adapter but I cant load localhost:1313 on the vm.

I tried using NAT and port forwarding but I have the same results, also tried the conection between the host and VM using ping and the VM can reach the host but the host cant connect to the VM so I guess that the problem is there but I dont know what to do now. The place where I am working uses IPv6 and I never worked with it before so maybe it has something to do with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Start your site as usual with `hugo server`, which makes it available at `http://localhost:1313`
2. Leave your Windows VM network settings at their defaults
3. In your Windows VM, navigate to `http://10.0.2.2:1313` to hit your hugo site

In a nutshell, `10.0.2.2` on your Windows VM (its default gateway) is equivalent to `localhost` on your linux host.

You can get the default gateway of your Windows VM by running `ipconfig` in Command Prompt.

Comment: If the link is from your own site, it is best to delete the link, otherwise it looks like you are using an answer merely to promote your site. Just make the answer so that it stands on its own.

Comment: Thank you for editing, I have retracted my Spam flag.